# How to check field value from database

Tags: php, html, database

I am taking three inputs from  user: UserName, FirstName, Email.

I want to check that if username is present in database then it should check its corresponding Firstname and email. And if all the three are correct then print message.

html code:

```
<html>
<body>
     Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
     FirstName: <input type="text" name="name"/>
     Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
       if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
           $usrnm=$_POST['username'];
           $name=$_POST['name'];
           $email=$_POST['email'];


           $user_name = "root";
           $password = "";
           $database = "show_your_talent";
           $server = "127.0.0.1";
           $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
           $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

           if ($db_found) 
           {
               $res="SELECT UserName,Fname,Email FROM reg WHERE UserName='$usrnm'";
               $result = mysql_query($res);

               $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
               if($count==1)
               {            
                   echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Password has been sent to your email id..')</script>";
               }
               else
               {
                   echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Wrong')</script>";
               }
           }
           mysql_close($db_handle);
       }
```

Comment: form tags are missing

Answer (score 2):

First Please use the form tag in html with method post.Then use this

```
if ($db_found) 
        {
               $name=$_POST['name'];
               $email=$_POST['email'];
               $res="SELECT * FROM reg WHERE UserName='".$usrnm."'";
               $res1="SELECT * FROM reg WHERE UserName='".$usrnm."' and Fname ='".$name."'";
               $res2="SELECT * FROM reg WHERE UserName='".$usrnm."' and Fname ='".$name."' and Email='".$email."'";
               $result = mysql_query($res);
               $result1= mysql_query($res1);
               $result2 = mysql_query($res2);
               $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
               $count1=mysql_num_rows($result1);
               $count2=mysql_num_rows($result2);
               if(($count==1) && ($count1==1) && ($count2==1) )
               {   
                     echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Password has been sent to your email id..')</script>";
               }
              else
              {
                   echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Wrong')</script>";
              }
        }
```

Comment: why u are you using this twice if(($count==1) && ($count2==1) && ($count2==1) )

Comment: Sorry Its  if(($count==1) && ($count1==1) && ($count2==1) ) like this..I have edited my answer

Comment: i tried to edit it but i couldn't ;-)

Comment: Oh..Thankyou for rectifying @AitazazKhan

Comment: welcome and vote up hahahha

Answer (score 2):

You're missing form tags and a (named) submit button to go along with your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`

Your code won't execute without it.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="handler.php" method="post">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
     FirstName: <input type="text" name="name"/>
     Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You then need to modify your query to:

```
$res="SELECT * FROM reg  WHERE UserName='$usrnm'  
          AND Email='$email' AND Fname='$name'";
```

while adding `stripslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` to your POST variables.

**I.e.:** (and doing it for all your POST variables)

```
$usrnm = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$usrnm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

Yet, it's best to use prepared statements; see further down below.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which would have signaled the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Including `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Something you are not doing.

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).